# What are the benefits of background mining compared to running it at a low CPU/IO priority?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, background

That is using

```
bg-mining-enable=true
bg-mining-min-idle-interval=5  # seconds
bg-mining-idle-threshold=200  # average idle %
```

in `/etc/monerod.conf` instead of something like

```
[Service]
...
Nice=5
CPUSchedulingPolicy=idle
IOSchedulingClass=idle
```

in `/etc/systemd/system/monerod.service`?

The latter can better utilize all available idle CPU resources, but I can imagine it can become starved if all of regular CPU priority capacity is used by other parts of the system. Does it pose a problem for the daemon (that is used just as a local, mining service)?

Answer (score 1):

> instead of something like...

The latter hobbles everything monerod is doing, not just mining.

The former just hobbles mining whilst the host is busy.

> Does it pose a problem for the daemon (that is used just as a local, mining service)?

Potentially yes. Mining still requires the txpool and latest height. So if you prevent (or slowing down) all the other functionality of monerod, you're impacting your mining further.

The background mining specific options make far more sense.